# Torsion elements of $SL_3(\mathbb{F}_p[x])$? (Quick question)

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, algebraic-geometry, geometric-group-theory, torsion-groups

Is every element of $SL_3(\mathbb{F}_p[x])$ a torsion element?

Here are my thoughts:

First of all, the group is noncommutative, so a torsion element is an element of finite order.

I'm thinking of examples of torsion elements:
Any generator (since a generator p times is the identity.)
Any element that has a rotation matrix as one of its factors.
And there are a bunch more examples.

Then I can't think of any element that does not have torsion in this group.

Could someone please refer me to a result that makes this more precise? Your help will be very much appreciated!

Comment: Torsion is always finite order (isn't it? )

Comment: $SL_3(R[x])\subset M_3(R)[x]$

Comment: Any generator for what?   $1\in \Bbb Z$ is not torsion.

Comment: A generator for the group. The group I am asking about.

Comment: @BobDobbs Thank you. Do you think this will help me find a torsion-free element? (Or prove there are none?)

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen Okay, let me think about this... We know the kernel is a normal subgroup of the group I'm wondering about. It's a normal subgroup with infinitely many elements that contains a power of every element...

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen So the homomorphism would take any element to the same matrix with all of the x terms deleted. An entry $2x+1$ would become $1$ for example.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen  But first, could you please let me know if you are thinking that this will show that there are NO torsion-free elements in $SL_3(\mathbb{F}_p[t])? I would really appreciate just that hint to see what I'm aiming for with this.

Comment: I now think that there may be non-torsion elements :-)

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen Every generator has finite order though. Does that mean all of the elements have finite order?

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen Yes! Thanks!

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen Thank you! I'm also going to keep looking for an actual element that would be torsion-free. It's not too complicated of a group after all.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen I'm leaning toward no torsion-free elements again... Does the fact that the group is infinitely presented mean anything?

Answer (score 3):

There are elements of infinite order in this group.

---

Consider the matrix
$$
A=\left(\begin{array}{cc}1&x\\ x&1+x^2\end{array}\right)\in SL_2(\Bbb{F}_p[x]).
$$
I claim that the order of $A$ is infinite.

Many ways to see this. See the comments by KCd below this post for a very compact argument.
Another explicit proof goes as follows.

Let $K$ be an algebraic closure  of the prime field, $K=\overline{\Bbb{F}_p}$.
The characteristic polynomial of $A$ is
$$
\chi_A(T)=T^2-(2+x^2)T+1.
$$
This has no zeros in $K$. For if $\lambda$ is a root of $\chi_A(T)$, then $1/\lambda$ is the other. But their sum $\lambda+1/\lambda=2+x^2$ is transcendental over the prime field. Hence the eigenvalues of $A$ cannot be roots of unity (those are all contained in $K$). Consequently $A^M\neq I_2$ for all
integers $M>0$. QED

It is trivial to extend $A$ to a $3\times3$ matrix in $SL_3(\Bbb{F}_p[x])$ by adding a $1$ along the diagonal. The resulting matrix must have infinite order as well.

---

My first solution (see the edit history) used the fact
that if
$g$ is any element of $K$, then
$$
\left(\begin{array}{cc}1&g\\ g&1+g^2\end{array}\right)\in SL_2(K)
$$
is a homomorphic image of $A$. Surely the orders of such matrices
are unconstrained, and hence $A$ must have infinite order. However, that only lead to a rather kludgy argument, so I removed it (some comments below may refer to it).

Comment: There should be a better way of using the finite quotient groups like $SL_3(\Bbb{F}_p[x]/\langle r(x)\rangle)$. This was just the first way that occured to me.

Comment: To show $A$ has infinite order is simple: for $n \geq 1$, write $A^n = \begin{pmatrix}a_n(x)&b_n(x)\\c_n(x)&d_n(x)\end{pmatrix}$ and show by induction  that the entries are monic with $\deg a_n(x) = 2n-2$, $\deg b_n(x) = \deg c_n(x) = 2n-1$, and $\deg d_n(x) = 2n$.  (Since $A$ is symmetric, in fact $b_n(x) = c_n(x)$, but that's not needed.) I found this by computing the  first $5$ powers of $A$ in $\mathbf Z[x]$ and looking  for patterns. So this works when viewing the matrix mod $p$ for all primes $p$. Nothing special about $p=3$.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen Thank you!! Bye! (And thanks for making me realize it's best to start with SL2!)

Comment: @KCd Thank you! Your answer is brilliant!

Comment: More generally, when $R$ is a commutative ring and $A = \begin{pmatrix} a(x)&b(x)\\c(x)&d(x)\end{pmatrix}$ in ${\rm M}_2(R[x])$ has entries that are monic with $\deg a(x) = m$, $\deg b(x) = \deg c(x) = m+1$, and $\deg d(x) = m+2$ for some integer $m \geq 0$, we have by induction on $n \geq 1$ that $A^n = \begin{pmatrix} a_n(x)&b_n(x)\\c_n(x)&d_n(x)\end{pmatrix}$ where the entries are monic with $\deg a_n(x) = mn+2n-2$, $\deg b_n(x) = \deg c_n(x) = mn+2n-1$, and $\deg d_n(x) = mn+2n$.

Comment: In the same spirit: if $M$ is a $2\times 2$ matrix over a field (maybe com. ring but I haven't checked the non-reduced case) with determinant 1 and trace $s$, and $x(n)$ is the sequence defined by the linear recurrence $x(n)=sx(n-1)-x(n-2)$, $x(0)=2$, $x(1)=s$ (next terms: $s^2-2$, $s^3-3s$, $s^4-4s^2+2$, $s^5-5s^3+5s$, $s^6-6s^4+9s^2-2$...), then the trace of $M^n$ is $x(n)$. If $s$ is transcendental over the prime field, $x(n)$ has degree $n$ with respect to $s$.

Answer (score 2):

In $\mathrm{GL}_n(\mathbf{F}_q(t))$, the characteristic polynomial $\det(B-x\mathrm{Id})$ of every element of finite order lies in $\mathbf{F}_q[x]$. Indeed, all its roots being roots of unity, they lie in $\overline{\mathbf{F}_q}$, hence so do their symmetric polynomials. Since the only elements in $\mathbf{F}_q(t)$ that are algebraic over over $\mathbf{F}_q$ are the constants, this observation follows.

Hence, consider a companion matrix $M$, relative to some monic polynomial $P$ of degree $n$ (here $n=3$) with coefficients in $\mathbf{F}_q(t)$, i.e., $P\in\mathbf{F}_q(t)[x]$. If $P\notin\mathbf{F}_q[x]$ (and $P(0)\neq 0$ to ensure that $M$ is invertible), then $M$ has infinite order. The determinant of $M$ is $P(0)=(-1)^{n-1}$.

For instance, for $n=2,3$ the following (companion, for the polynomials $x^2-tx+1$, $x^3-tx^2-1$ respectively) matrices are in $\mathrm{SL}_n(\mathbf{F}_p[t])$ and have infinite order and determinant 1:
$$\begin{pmatrix}0 & -1\\1 & t\end{pmatrix},\quad \begin{pmatrix}0 & 0 & 1\\ 1 & 0 & 0\\0 & 1 & t\end{pmatrix}.$$

Of course this applies to non-companion matrices. For instance the one in [Jyrki's answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4886712/35400): the trace is not constant, hence it has infinite order.

This is an iff condition: if all coefficients of the characteristic polynomial are constant with respect to $t$, then these are roots of unity, so some power of the matrix is unipotent (i.e. char. polynomial $(x-1)^n$ and hence has finite order (since the characteristic is finite). This yields a immediate algorithm to check whether a matrix in $\mathrm{GL}_n(\mathbf{F}_q(t))$ has finite order: iff its char. pol. is constant w.r.t $t$.